# How to create a cell with graphics and text placeholder for Slideshow?

Tags: output-formatting, cells, slideshows

I have some graphics in a notebook that I need to place in a slideshow and then add some commentary later by typing it in. The setup I an attempting to replicate is on slide 3 of a new Slideshow (the image of the wild-cat with formatted text next to it).

Minimal example of what I have tried.

```
Grid[{{
   Column[{Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}], Grid[{{"Stats grid", 2.2}}]}],
   TextCell[Placeholder["Commentary"], "SubitemParagraph"]
   }}, Alignment -> {Left, Top}]
```

[image]

I cannot enter text into the `"Commentary"` placeholder in either the notebook that this is created in nor in the slideshow notebook when I copy and paste the cell.

The slideshow is a combination of results from a few notebooks and I can't place all the code in the slideshow notebook. It would not be manageable to maintain.

How do I generate a cell that behaves as the *"wild-cat"* cell in that appears in a new slideshow?  A solution that allows me to include a placeholder for the copy-n-paste and then keeps the editing of the text interactive as with the *"wild-cat"* cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `TextCell` with `Style` and print the whole as a new `TextCell` with explicit `"ShowStringCharacters" -> False` option (this option is set by default for the `"Output"` cells, but the cells intended for interactive input have no this option by default):

```
CellPrint@TextCell[
  Grid[{{Column[{Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}], Grid[{{"Stats grid", 2.2}}]}], 
     Style[Placeholder["Commentary"], "SubitemParagraph"]}}, 
   Alignment -> {Left, Top}], "Text", "ShowStringCharacters" -> False]
```

[image: screenshot]

Now you can select the placeholder and type into it. Typed text will have the style `"SubitemParagraph"`, subscripts and superscripts can be created using usual keyboard shortcuts:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Nope. As you type the *Commentary* the text in the grid under the plot turns to `FullForm`. Notice the quotes around *Stats grid*. The real grid under the plot has formatting that turns into `SubscriptBoxes` and the like. It becomes no longer readable.

Comment: @Edmund I have updated the answer, please try again.

Comment: That seems to be the ticket. Where did you find the `"ShowStringCharacters"`option?  Is it undocumented? (+1)

Comment: It is basically [documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShowStringCharacters.html), but understanding of the specifics of working of this option I have found by experimentation: it doesn't simply turns on/off display of the quotation marks `"`, but also triggers rendering of the string representation of boxes ([the linear syntax](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/xp4fuxv_ODk/tOqGkuy3RWgJ)).

Comment: @Edmund If my solution works for you, please Accept it.

Comment: It is good practice to let questions sit for at least day after the last answer/edit to see what else pops up. Don't worry, I wont forget to return to this question for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

Using TextGrid instead may work for you:

```
TextGrid[{{Column[{Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}], Grid[{{"Stats grid", 2.2}}]}],
    TextCell[Placeholder["Commentary"], "SubitemParagraph"]}}, 
 Alignment -> {Left, Top}]
```

Comment: `TextGrid` does not cooperate with the `Grid` under the graphic. As soon as I start to type the grid under the graphic switches into `FullForm`.  The actual grids have lots of formatting and it turns into `SubscriptBox`es and the like.  Also the text I type into the `Placeholder` is not formatted in the requested style.